# Replace all items in section in UICollectionView with one item (combine cells)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that uses flow layout with sections.
On some user action I need to replace all items in specific section with one new item and animate that change (I hope I'll be able to use interactive transition for this).
Basically - cells in section should merge to a single cell with animation. Is this possible by using 2 different layouts and custom transition class? Can anyone please provide advice on how to do it better?

Comment: what do you mean with the sentence " cells should animate merging to one cell" so you want that all the info inside to more cell go into a cell?

Comment: I changed text: I want to animate merging of cells in specific section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, maybe I should have read more about UICollectionViews before asking this question.
I managed to achieve desired effect by using this algorithm

1. Copy old section data array to some temporary array
2. Replace old section data in data source with new array with only one needed object.
3. Call `[_collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{}` and inside the block go over all existing items in this section and call `[_collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:itemsToRemove];`
4. Call `[_collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:indexPath.section]]];`
5. Call `[_collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section]];`

Then, if I need to restore section back, I need to repeat these steps, but replace section in datasource with that temporary array with original data, remove single existing item (cell) and insert all items (cells) to section.